# How to set MassTransit rate limit dynamically?

Tags: c#, masstransit

How can use the IPipeRouter to dynamically set the rate limit

Currently, I use UseRateLimit configuration method as following. But I need to change the rate limit dynamically.

```
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("SomeEvent", x =>
                {
                    x.UseRateLimit(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                    x.ConfigureConsumer<SomeEventConsumer>(context);
                });
```

I see that UseRateLimit method has router parameter with type IPipeRouter.The explanation of the parameter is

> The control pipe used to adjust the rate limit dynamically.

But I couldn't find an example on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented/supported way to dynamically adjust the rate limit.

There are legacy methods that allowed such a change, but the use of them is complicated (and thus why it isn't supported).

```cs
var router = new PipeRouter();

cfg.UseRateLimit(100, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), router);
```

Saving that pipe router is up to you, but somewhere else in the code, you could call:

```cs
await router.SetRateLimit(10);
```

And it can be adjusted up or down to suit your purpose.

> Again, this is not supported but *could* work for you.